# How to make the list into table Django?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have got an a list:

```
[{'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)', 'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...', 'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SEO'], 'employer': 'Hastra Agency', 'salary': 'None - 60000 RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73732873'}, {'name': 'Веб-разработчик golang, react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets', 'description': 'Обязанности: Стек: react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets, golang Поддержка текущего проекта с сущест...', 'key_skills': [], 'employer': 'МегаСео', 'salary': '150000 - None RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73705217'}, ....., ......
```

Array is with 10 lists.

How can I make it into table? *CSV* file?
Columns are ***name**, **description**, **key_skills ...***
Rows are ***1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...***

I need to make this table in Django, how can I do it?